# Rails order a find by counts of items on another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails so please let me know if I am thinking about things incorrectly...

My task is:

I have a Users table and a Posts table.  I want to find out which users have the most posts.

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use counter cache for that purpose, then sort by the column. See reference explanation here [Rails counter_cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972280/rails-counter-cache)

```
#model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts

  scope :popular, :order('posts_count')
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true
end


#migration
add_column :users, :posts_count, :integer, :default => 0
```